# RadioButton Text is not hiding

Tags: c#, razor

My Code:

```xml
<div class="rdoTest">@Html.RadioButton("rdoTest", "Test", new { @onchange = "rdoReportTypeChange(this,true,true)" })&nbsp;Test
</div>
```

I used `var rdoTest =$('#rdoTest');rdoTest.hide();`

Only the radio button is hiding but the text (`Test`) is not hiding.

Comment: You should provide us with the compiled html. If you're not a .NET expert like me, it may be hard to know whats wrong.

Answer (score 0):

May be you want to do next:

```
var rdoTest =$('.rdoTest');rdoTest.hide();
```

Sign # mean select by Id, but you want select by class name.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you set a class rdoTest on the radiobutton, but in your jquery you query for a an id?

```
$('.rdoTest').hide();
```